# Java regex for special URL

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I'm trying to write a regex to match a special kind of HTTP URL:

```
http://<any-string-of-1-or-more-chars>/#<any-string-of-0-or-more-chars>
```

So the string has 4 segments:

1. The string literal: "*http://*"; then
2. Any string of 1+ chars; then
3. The string literal: "*/#*"; then
4. Any string of 0+ char

Examples of "passing" strings:

- http://example.com/#
- http://example.com/#fizz
- http://z.example.com/#

etc. My best attempt is:

```
String regex = "http://*/#*";
```

However when I try it out:

```
String test = "http://example.com/#";
String regex = "http://*/#*";
if(test.matches(regex))
    System.out.println("I match!");
else
    System.err.println("I don't match!");
```

Where am I going wrong, and what should my regex be (and why)?

Comment: What does `#*` in regex mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regex if you want to match 1 or more any character then use `.+` and for 0 or more use `.*`

It is better to go through a good regex tutorial like: http://regular-expressions.info

You can use this regex:

```
String regex = "^https?://.+?/#.*$";
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava (+1) - 3 followup questions: (1) Why do you prefix the regex with "^"? (2) What does the "?" mean in ".+?"? And (3) What do you suffix the regex with "$"? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) Better to use line start/end anchors `^ and $` to make sure your match is most accurate. 2) In the `.+?` `?` is used to make matching non-greedy or reluctant. 3) Same as 1).

Comment: @CalifornianAcorn I would suggest you read the link suggested rather than asking to be spoon fed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - why bog the mind down with tedious details when you can just crowdsource?

Answer (score 0):

> any-string-of-1-or-more-chars

this is `.+`, not `*`

> any-string-of-0-or-more-chars

this is `.*`, not `*`

Comment: need to make the first `.` not be greedy, so the first should be `.+?`